# How to kill an Electro Wizard in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

The Electro Wizard is a card that will be soon released in Clash Royale. I need a clear solution to take him out without spells. Any ideas?

Comment: The Electro Wizard has undergone many balance changes...

Answer (score 1):

Swarm him with a skeleton army or gobbling gang for a +1 trade, or if he is with similar health units, a fireball plus zap/log should give you a good trade.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill it by either deploying a swarm unit nearby (Barbarians, Skeleton Army, etc.) or by using a high-damage unit (Mini P.E.K.K.A., Knight, etc.)
*Also note that a Level 7 Fireball one-shots a Level 1 Electro Wizard. (**Update: *No longer one-shots after the 23/1/2017 Update.*)**

Comment: fireball does not work after the Jan 23 update

Comment: eWiz "zap" effect stuns and causes retargeting.  Slow single shot troops like Mini PEKKA aren't the best against him.  Swarms are pretty much the best answer, or something that can Tank while your tower does work.

Comment: Placing a Mini P.E.K.K.A. on the same tile or very close to the Electro Wizard may work, because of his relatively low HP. @EBongo

Answer (score 0):

Its attack speed is super slow (1.7 sec between each shot) thus practically anything could kill it quite fast. The following units could work:

- Miner : High health, +1 Elixir Trade, Good DPS
- Valkyrie : Same as above, even trade
- Barbarians: Highly effective, High Health, Good Dps, -1 Elixir Trade
- Skeleton Army: So many... +1 Elixir Trade
- Defenses: I mean, the tower would finish the Electro Wizard and the defense would help clear any support troops or any troops it is supporting